# How to send a default parameter in method (Python)

Tags: python

This is the class:

```
import pyautogui
import cv2
import numpy as np
class VidRec:
    def screen(self,fps=12.0,time=10):
        SCREEN_SIZE = tuple(pyautogui.size())
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"XVID")
        out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, self.fps, (SCREEN_SIZE))
        for i in range(int(self.time * self.fps)):
            img = pyautogui.screenshot()
            # convert these pixels to a proper numpy array to work with OpenCV
            frame = np.array(img)
            # convert colors from BGR to RGB
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            # write the frame
            out.write(frame)
            # show the frame
            # cv2.imshow("screenshot", frame)
            # if the user clicks q, it exits
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
                break

        # make sure everything is closed when exited
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        out.release()
```

How I call it:

```
import tasks

p = tasks.VidRec()
p.screen()
```

I get an error even though I made default parameters in the class "def screen(self,fps=12.0,time=10):"

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi", fourcc, self.fps, (SCREEN_SIZE))
AttributeError: 'VidRec' object has no attribute 'fps'
```

Comment: `fps`  is not the same as `self.fps`. There is no code in your question that initialises `self.fps`. Maybe you intended to do `self.fps = fps`?

Comment: The error states that the class does not have an `fps` attribute, and it’s absolutely right.

Comment: Yes that is what i need for default fps which is equal to 12.0 to be the value of self.fps. but isn't self.fps is fps?

Comment: No. `self.fps` is a member of the class instance.  `fps` is simply a scoped local variable, in the `screen` method only.

Comment: As the other comments mentioned, you have not initialized and defined a **class attribute** called `fps` inside the class. You have only passed an argument called `fps` to the `screen` method. Two different things. Have a read [here](https://dzone.com/articles/python-class-attributes-vs-instance-attributes) on how classes and attributes work.